# Variable scope: Global variable inside function

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to assign a JSON array to a variable as follows:

```
$.getJSON("tljson.json",function(result){
  items = JSON.stringify(result);
});
```

And then calling that variable outside the function:

```
timeline.draw (items,options);
```

Using alert (items) inside the getJSON function works, however, outside of the function, it just returns 'undefined'. I thought this would work, as I declared items as a global variable in the getJSON function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably not waiting for the `getJSON` function to complete. It's **asynchronous** which means that code under it will execute *before* code in the callback function.

```
alert(1);
$.getJSON("tljson.json",function(result){
  alert(2);
  items = JSON.stringify(result);
});
alert(3);
```

The example above actually alerts `1` then `3` then `2`. Note that the `3` is before the `2`.

In order to fix your code, you'll need to wait until the callback function is called so that it can assign a value to `items` before you try to use that variable. Coming up with a solution may depend on your situation, but an easy idea is to call some function from within your callback.

```
$.getJSON("tljson.json",function(result){
  items = JSON.stringify(result);
  doSomethingWithItems();
});

function doSomethingWithItems() {
  alert(items); // Correctly alerts items.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your code is executing before response from getJSON is received. Use it like:

```
  function afterGetJSON(items) {
    timeline.draw (items,options);
  }

  $.getJSON("tljson.json",function(result){
    items = JSON.stringify(result);
    afterGetJSON(items);

  });
```